# Can I skip the prologue?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

Today, I formatted my PC for the new Windows 10. Before doing that, I saved the whole Steam folder.

I've re-installed everything, copied back games on Steam and all are working fine, but now I launched GTA V to play online and asks me to do the prologue. I'm a bit confused since GTA V saves are made on the cloud (AFAIK).

Is there a way to skip the prologue? I just want to play online.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a way to skip it, but if you're familliar with the game you should be able to rush through it in 10-12 minutes. Your goal is Franklin's bed after the little race thing, since that's the first save point.

This is somewhat annoying but fits with their design choices: sometimes when online fails it throws you directly back into single player, and you don't really want it to load into the prologue *then*.

Also, their odd UI forces you to load into the singleplayer and use the escape menu *there* if you want to start a online invite/friends/crew/solo game.

Thankfully after loading into any game mode once the load times are much reduced.

Answer (score 1):

You cant skip it but if you die 3 times you have the option to skip that section. do it over first when exiting the bank then when michael and brad get shot if  u skip those sections u wont have to do much